# In Metronic 'gulp --demo1' command is not generating css , js , and media folder?

Tags: metronic

I have Metronic theme folder and when I use 'gulp --demo1' command It should generate CSS, js, plugins, and media folder but it is generating only the plugins folder. I have followed all the instructions given in the [documenation](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=html-quick-start). What is going wrong?